# Pytesseract: Error opening data file \\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\en.traineddata

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to use pytesseract on Jupyter Notebook.

- Windows 10 x64
- Running Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda3, Python 3.6.1) with administrative privilege
- The work directory containing TIFF file is in different drive (Z:)

When I run the following code:

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

tessdata_dir_config = '--tessdata-dir "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata"'

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('Multi_page24bpp.tif'), lang='en', config = tessdata_dir_config))
```

I get the following error:

```
TesseractError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-c1dcbc33cde4> in <module>()
     11 # tessdata_dir_config = '--tessdata-dir "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata"'
     12 
---> 13 print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('Multi_page24bpp.tif'), lang='en'))
     14 # print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test-european.jpg'), lang='fra'))

C:\Users\cpcho\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in image_to_string(image, lang, boxes, config)
    123         if status:
    124             errors = get_errors(error_string)
--> 125             raise TesseractError(status, errors)
    126         f = open(output_file_name, 'rb')
    127         try:

TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file \\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\en.traineddata')
```

I found these two references helpful but I am missing something:
https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/issues/50
https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/issues/64

Thank you for your time on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post, observed two possible issues.

1. All the trained language data should be saved in `TESSDATA_PREFIX`,
   a Windows environmental variable, which is at `C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata` in your case.
2. The `tesseract` trained English data is named `eng.traineddata` (i.e. `'eng'`) unless you modified its name. Refer to this [Tesseract Data Files](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files) for more information.

In addition, for `pytesseract` to read the image file `Image.open()`, you may include the full file path (e.g. `'z:\\path\\to\\image'`) if the image file is unable to locate.

Hope to this.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to set environment variable you can pass as an argument as well

For example:

First, do your imports

```
    import pytessetact
    from PIL import Image
```

And now configure pytesseract

```
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:/path_to_your_tesseract.exe"
    tessdata_dir_config = '--tessdata-dir "C:/path_to_your_tessdata_folder"'

    pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config=tessdata_dir_config)
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. I tried all solutions on Google, without success. Finally, I solved the problem by replacing.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
```

with

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'.
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Error is still there. Maybe because I used 'Devnagari' language

Answer (score -2):

Day 1 -all works;
Day 2 -this error;
on second computer all works...
5 hours later: ===i find ANSWER in my mind===

From "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata" copy 'eng.traineddata' to "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR"

its work =\

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31582133)