# Could not initialise terreract

Tags: python, image, tesseract

### pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file \Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')

Here is the thing i have already placed the tesseract path in my Environment Variable , also i have created a "TESSDATA_PREFIX" variable with the path to the tessdata folder in tesseract by following the answer in this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45255794), also following on the accepted answer's advice i gave full path to my image locations , ***but i am still facing the "Could not initialize the tesseract issue"***

*PS: I do have a file named eng.traineddata at location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata*"

Here's my python code:

```
from pytesseract import *
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
configs = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata\\configs"
from PIL import Image

print(image_to_string(Image.open('D:\\PycharmFiles\\ImageProcessing\\sample.png')))
print(image_to_string(Image.open('D:\\PycharmFiles\\ImageProcessing\\sample.png'), lang='eng', config=configs))
```

Comment: Did you restart your pc after setting env variable?