# Got error from Text recognition using Tesseract in pycharm(Windows)

Tags: python, ocr

I tried to read text inside the image using pytesseract and openCV in pycharm editor(windows). It display image but when read the text it show error.
Here is my code.

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'
image = cv2.imread('test2.png')

image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
height,width,_ =image.shape
print(height,width)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image)) # ****

cv2.imshow('Output', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

According to this code when I type and run

```
 print (pytesseract.image_to_string(image))
```

It showed error like follow.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Last Update\Uni of Mora\L4S1\FYP\new python project\HTMLCodeGenerator1\test detection.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image))
  File "D:\Last Update\Uni of Mora\L4S1\FYP\new python project\HTMLCodeGenerator1\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 409, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "D:\Last Update\Uni of Mora\L4S1\FYP\new python project\HTMLCodeGenerator1\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 412, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "D:\Last Update\Uni of Mora\L4S1\FYP\new python project\HTMLCodeGenerator1\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 287, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "D:\Last Update\Uni of Mora\L4S1\FYP\new python project\HTMLCodeGenerator1\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 263, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

I tried various ways. But it doesn't work. I changed the environment variable, download test data again but it doesn't work. How I solve this.

Comment: try to uninstall pytesseract and reinstall through pycharm terminal with '''pip install pytesseract'''

Comment: I added language type. It's work

Answer (score -1):

I think your main problem is with TESSDATA_PREFIX not being in Env Variables

See this answer
[Pytesseract: Error opening data file \\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\en.traineddata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45249873/pytesseract-error-opening-data-file-program-files-x86-tesseract-ocr-en-tr)

Comment: I thinl I forgot to add language type.After that it's work now/ Thank you...

Comment: Please don't post links to other answers as answers. Just leave a comment to nominateethis question as a duplicate of the older question.

Comment: Okay Will Keep Sure Next Time